# how to add in dataframe of NaT of perticular cell to different date

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to convert Nat of perticular cell value from excel to different date.
First Im checking for Nat, then I want to overwrite to new date. But overwrite is not happening in dataframe and below error message is printed

```
        if pd.isnull(df_TS.loc['Name']['Actual_date']):
            df_TS['Name']['Actual_date'] =  pd.to_datetime(new_date) 
            print(df_TS['Name']['Actual_date'])
```

---

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lk38988\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2898, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 253

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python_scripts\UTAS_BPCU_WAS_updation_Ver3.py", line 173, in <module>
    df_TS[each_TS][temp_actual_date] =  start_date #df_TS[each_TS][temp_actual_date].fillna(end_date)
  File "C:\Users\lk38988\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2906, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\lk38988\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2900, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 253
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want and your input?

Comment: In excel, there are dates and in some places no dates. I want to replace the dataframe of  perticular cell of Nat to different date and save to other excel through dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You have got the right idea to use `loc` method.

But what you seem to be missing is the way Pandas is a so called *array language*. That is each operation applies to the whole column and not to a value in each column individually. So in Pandas you rarely use `if` as it is a scalar operator.

Let's proceed with a toy example. Here we create a data frame with three rows indexed by an `id` field with another column that stores datetime.

```python
import pandas as pd

df_TS = pd.DataFrame([dict(id=1, actual_date='2020-12-23'),
                      dict(id=2, actual_date=None),
                      dict(id=3, actual_date=None)])
df_TS = df_TS.set_index('id')
df_TS['actual_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_TS['actual_date'])
```

Here is how it looks like:

| id | actual_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-23 |
| 2 | NaT |
| 3 | NaT |

Now here is how to update only the NaT rows.

```python
df_TS.loc[df_TS['actual_date'].isna(), 'actual_date'] = pd.Timestamp.now()
```

Here we do the following:

1. Use `loc` to select only the rows where `actual_date` is not specified for the left hand side of the assignment.
2. select only the `actual_date` column out of these rows to get a `pd.Series` object
3. Use Pandas magic to assign all elements of the Series the same scalar value from the right hand side.

| id | actual_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-23 00:00:00.000000 |
| 2 | 2021-01-13 22:26:28.567794 |
| 3 | 2021-01-13 22:26:28.567794 |

I hope that is what you wanted to get. Also notice how the representation of the date in the first row has changed.

---

**P.S.** The error message that you were getting seems to be related to a different line in your code and manifests a different problem.